# Какие стилистические и пунктуационные ошибки сделаны в этом тексте?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика, семантика

Увидев этот фильм ещё в детстве, он запомнился мне на многие годы, по прошествии многих лет, его хочется смотреть вновь и вновь. Настолько вызывает восхищение умение и мастерство французского кинематографа. И вряд ли можно увидеть похожий сюжет, как в этом незабываемом фильме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Увиденный еще в детстве, этот фильм запомнился мне на многие годы, и по прошествии времени его хочется смотреть вновь и вновь, настолько восхищает  мастерство французского кинематографа.  А такой сюжет, как в этом незабываемом фильме, вряд ли еще можно встретить.

Стилистические погрешности: повторы, семантическая избыточность, нечеткий синтаксический строй, неясно необозначенная связь предложений в тексте.

Comment: Спасибо,  Vera !

Answer (score 4):

1. Увидев... он запомнился.

Грамматически невозможная конструкция, поскольку в деепричастном обороте всегда тот же производитель действия, что в основной части предложения (здесь как бы "фильм запомнился мне, увидев сам себя"). С сохранением деепричастного оборота возможно либо "будучи увиден мною... он запомнился", либо "**Увидев... я его запомнил...**" .

2. Предложение "Настолько вызывает..." имеет сильную логическую связь с предыдущим высказыванием (выражает причину желания пересматривать фильм), поэтому разделение на предложения в этом месте воспринимается как искусственный разрыв. Поэтому лучше отделить от первого предложения вторую часть и объединить её с этим предложением; "умение" и "мастерство" обычно свойственны людям (кинематографистам):

**По прошествии многих лет его хочется смотреть вновь и вновь - такое восхищение вызывает у меня мастерство французских кинематографистов.**

3. Похожий сюжет, ... как в этом фильме.

Здесь нет прямого указания, "на что" похож, а добавленное уточнение не согласовано с упомянутой похожестью. В результате создаётся впечатление, что по ошибке применён оборот "похожий, как" вместо "похожий на что". Чтобы укоротить полное выражение (сюжет, похожий на сюжет этого фильма), можно перед уточнением добавить "такой" (**... похожий сюжет - такой, как в этом незабываемом фильме.**)

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander!

Comment: Alex_ander, а вы не могли бы привести свой вариант текста. С одной стороны, там много погрешностей, с другой - он достаточно выразителен. Как записать его содержание грамотно и одновременно сохранить свежесть и непосредственность выражаемых чувств?

Comment: Это сильно отличалось бы от авторского варианта в сторону упрощения ->
Этот фильм мне запомнился с детства. И сейчас, по прошествии многих лет, мне хочется смотреть его и смотреть - столь восхитительно мастерство французских кинематографистов. Да и подобного сюжета ни в одном фильме больше не встретишь.